# To create the records in the object with the help of http response in rest api in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, callout

I want to create the record with the help of response which has come from the serverside,
now Iam able to get the response in the js and stringify the response but iam not able to match the fieldsto create the record

HTML CODE IS

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Rest Service Forms">
        <lightning-layout>
            <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-small">
                    <!--    <p>
                            <lightning-input label="Enter the Number"></lightning-input>
                        </p>
                       
                        <p>
                            <lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" name="save" label="Submit"  onclick={subBtn} ></lightning-button>
                        </p>-->
                        <div><lightning-input label = " Enter the Number " ></lightning-input><br/></div>
                        <div>
                            <lightning-button label="Submit" onclick={subBtn} ></lightning-button>
                            
                        </div>
                
            </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>
            </lightning-card>
        </template>
```

JS Code is

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable getter-return */
/* eslint-disable consistent-return */
import { LightningElement,wire} from 'lwc';
import restServiceCls from '@salesforce/apex/restServiceApexClass.restServiceApexClassId';
import { createRecord, getRecord  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const fieldArray = ['Rest_Service__c.Id__c','Rest_Service__c.completed__c', 'Rest_Service__c.title__c', 'Rest_Service__c.userId__c'];

export default class RestService extends LightningElement {

    recordId;
    rd;
    jsonobjectid;
    jsonobjeccompleted;
    jsonobjecttitle;
    recordjsonid;
    recordjsonCompleted;
    recordjsontitle;
    recordjsonuserId;
    num1;

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: fieldArray})
    recordInserted;

    subBtn(){
        console.log('hiiiiii...........');
        console.log('number submitted..') ;  
        
        this.outputText = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value;
        console.log('this.outputText'+  this.outputText);
        console.log('submit button is click');
      
        restServiceCls({num1:this.outputText}).then(response => {
            this.record=response;

          console.log('record json is is' +this.record);
          console.log('response records are ----'+JSON.stringify(this.record));
          
           this.recordjson=JSON.stringify(this.record);
           this.jsonobject = JSON.parse(this.recordjson);
           console.log('jsonobject----'+this.jsonobject);
         


          this.recordjsontitle=JSON.stringify(this.record.title);
           this.jsonobjecttitle = JSON.parse(this.recordjsontitle);
          console.log('recordjsontitle----'+this.jsonobjecttitle);
          
          this.recordjsonCompleted=JSON.stringify(this.record.completed);
          this.jsonobjeccompleted = JSON.parse(this.recordjsonCompleted);
          console.log('recordjsonCompleted----'+this.jsonobjeccompleted);

          this.recordjsonid=JSON.stringify(this.record.id);
          this.jsonobjectid = JSON.parse(this.recordjsonid);
          console.log('recordjsonid----'+this.jsonobjectid);
          
          this.recordjsonuserId=JSON.stringify(this.record.userId);
          this.jsonobjectuserId = JSON.parse(this.recordjsonuserId);
          console.log('recordjsonuserId----'+this.jsonobjectuserId);
          //this.rd=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.record.id));
         // console.log('rd---'+this.rd);
    const Field = {'title__c': this.jsonobjecttitle, 'completed__c': this.jsonobjeccompleted, 'Id__c': this.jsonobjectid, 'userId__c': this.jsonobjectuserId};
 
    const recordInput = {apiName : 'Rest_Service__c',Field};
   console.log('Fields------'+Field);
    console.log('recordInput----'+recordInput);
   
    
  /*  console.log('recordInput stringify'+JSON.stringify(recordInput));
    console.log('fields stringify'+JSON.stringify(Field));*/
    createRecord(recordInput).then(res =>{
        console.log('Rest_Service has been created: ', res.id);
        this.recordId = res.id;
         
    }).catch(error =>{ 
        console.log('Error are creating account', error.body.message);
    }); 
 
}) 
    }
    
}
```

Class code is

```
public class restServiceApexClass {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable =true)
    public static map<String, Object>  restServiceApexClassId(integer num1) {

        map<String, Object> mapJsonData = new map<String, Object>();
        String strResponse = null;
        if(num1!= 0) {
       
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(); 
        httpRequest.setEndpoint('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'+num1);
        httpRequest.setMethod('GET'); 
        try {  
            Http http = new Http();   
            HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);  
        
      
            while(httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 302) {
                httpRequest.setEndpoint(httpResponse.getHeader('Location'));
                httpResponse = new Http().send(httpRequest);
               

            }

            if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {  
                strResponse = httpResponse.getBody();  
            } 

        else {  
            throw new CalloutException(httpResponse.getBody());  
        } 
      
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {  
        throw ex;  
    }  
}   
    if(!String.isBlank(strResponse)) {
        mapJsonData = (map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(strResponse);
        System.debug('mapJsonData ===> '+mapJsonData);
 }


    if(!mapJsonData.isEmpty()) {
        return mapJsonData;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }          
           
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the syntax. RecordInput object format is:

```
{
  "apiName": "Account",
  "fields": {
    "Name": "Universal Containers"
  }
}
```

Fields is the required property of RecordInput object and it must be available in your object structure as it is.
Now when you use a variable name directly in the object, the destructring model take that name as the key itself and that is why in place of 'fields' your are sending 'Field' in object, that is where createRecord is not able to identify the fields. There are 2 options, either you modify variable name **'Field'** to **'fields'** or in the recordInput variable define it explicitly.

Option1:

```
const fields = {'title__c': this.jsonobjecttitle, 'completed__c': this.jsonobjeccompleted, 'Id__c': this.jsonobjectid, 'userId__c': this.jsonobjectuserId};
 
const recordInput = {apiName : 'Rest_Service__c', fields };
```

Option2:

```
const Field = {'title__c': this.jsonobjecttitle, 'completed__c': this.jsonobjeccompleted, 'Id__c': this.jsonobjectid, 'userId__c': this.jsonobjectuserId};
 
const recordInput = {apiName : 'Rest_Service__c', "fields" : Field};
```

Comment: I worked me thank you....